# Update message with real-time voting in slack

Tags: python, bots, slack, slack-api

I want to make a bot in a slack that sends a vote and in the same message in real time shows who voted how. I wrote such an application using slack_bolt, but now it only shows the last voter, overwriting the previous one. How can this be done? It seems that this is easy, but I just can't figure out how.

```
from slack_bolt.adapter.socket_mode import SocketModeHandler
from src.settings import Settings
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
settings = Settings()
app = App(token=settings.slack_bot_token)


static_select = {
    "blocks": [
        {
            "type": "divider"
        },
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": "Pick an item from the dropdown list"
            },
            "accessory": {
                "type": "static_select",
                "placeholder": {
                    "type": "plain_text",
                    "text": "Select an item",
                    "emoji": True
                },
                "options": [
                    {
                        "text": {
                            "type": "plain_text",
                            "text": "0",
                            "emoji": True
                        },
                        "value": "value-0"
                    },
                    {
                        "text": {
                            "type": "plain_text",
                            "text": "0,5",
                            "emoji": True
                        },
                        "value": "value-1"
                    },
                    {
                        "text": {
                            "type": "plain_text",
                            "text": "1",
                            "emoji": True
                        },
                        "value": "value-2"
                    },
                    {
                        "text": {
                            "type": "plain_text",
                            "text": "2",
                            "emoji": True
                        },
                        "value": "value-3"
                    }
                ],
                "action_id": "static_select-action"
            }
        }
    ]
}


@app.command("/go_poll")
def hello_command(ack, client):
    ack()
    client.chat_postMessage(channel="#random", blocks=static_select['blocks'])


@app.action("static_select-action")
def option_chosen(ack, body, client, logger):
    ack()
    selected_option = body['actions'][0]['selected_option']['text']['text']
    res = client.chat_update(
        channel=body["channel"]["id"],
        ts=body["message"]["ts"],
        as_user=True,
        attachments=[{"pretext": f'@{body["user"]["username"]}:{selected_option} '}]
    )
    logger.info(res)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    SocketModeHandler(app, settings.slack_app_token).start()
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the attachment parameter in chat_update does not add a new attachment, but rather redefines the attachments of the message, hence why you only see the most recent vote.

A workaround would be to retrieve the existing attachments first, add the new vote, then call client.chat_update.

Explore the data you receive in the ***body**** object, you should be able to see information about your original message, and grab the attachments from there.